# Does "multiple" mean simply "more than one" or is it better used to connote division, duplication, or repetition?

Tags: meaning, connotation

First, "more than one" and "many" are *acceptable* meanings for "[multiple](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multiple)."

> 1 : consisting of, including, or involving more than one: multiple
> births, multiple choices
>
> 2 : MANY, MANIFOLD multiple achievements: He suffered multiple
> injuries in the accident.

We could stop there, but we can do better. "Multiple," many authorities and kibitzers contend, is best used to describe separation, repetition, or division from a whole. Most of Merriam-Webster's definition carry this idea of repetition. [Michael Kandel of the MLA](https://style.mla.org/many-or-multiple/) agrees`:

> But in my view multiple is often not a good synonym for many, meaning
> “a large number,” because multiple has traditionally had a narrower
> sense: that many elements or parts belong to or are involved in one
> thing or one event.

A deft writer can express herself vividly by precisely using "multiple" when it's called for. It's correct to use "multiple" to mean "more than one," but I think it's less than industrious.

In my experience, in the past twenty years writers have come to use "multiple" as a fancier, more authoritative way to say "many." Kandel suggests that this usage fits squarely into Bryan Garner's definition of jargon: use the longer word when the shorter one will do.

In a stale thread in [English Forward](https://www.englishforums.com/English/MultipleVsMany/brgrbk/post.htm), more than a few (and here I might well say "multiple," though "many" or "a lot" is fine) commenters vent on the bloated use of "multiple." One mirrors the prescriptive, grumpy old man in me, at least on this topic:

> I am getting increasingly irritated by the indiscriminate use of the
> word "multiple" when a few, many or several will do: multiple gun
> shots; multiple perpetrators; multiple bruises, etc. It has taken over
> in the media because it sounds more important.

(I'm not sure, but English Forward appears to be British.)

**[Examples](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multiple#examples):**

The spokesperson said that the pursuit lasted for more than two hours and resulted in **multiple** near collisions involving other drivers, pedestrians and the NYPD.
—Victoria Murphy, Town & Country, 18 May 2023

*Read **many**.  The idea here is that the pursuit caused numerous accidents, not repeated or similar.*

Poets should aim for each reader to have **multiple** ways to navigate a poem.
—Elizabeth Myong, Dallas News, 18 May 2023

*Ok with **multiple**.  One people engendering different interpretations.*

McKean said the food truck drew patrons from **multiple** bars in the area despite El Chila's best efforts to clear the parking lot.
—The Indianapolis Star, 17 May 2023

*Clearly **many**.  It might be good food after a night of drinking, but the only point is that there are a lot of drunks, not that they are varied or distinct.*

Comment: A Reddit discussion from 2021 offers a discussion about my question - the *best* connotation of "multiple."

The poster says a high-school English teacher told him (don't all the prescriptives start this way?) that it was grammatically incorrect to 

'use the word “multiple” to mean “several” or “many” or “numerous”, say, people in a group, or M&Ms in a bag, it was incorrect. Multiple was only correct to describe something like “multiple births” as in twins or triplets.'

This is the gist of my post.  https://www.reddit.com/r/grammar/comments/n1758r/proper_use_of_the_word_multiple/

Comment: Even more authoritative that Reddit (ha!), MLA also supports a more nuanced use of "multiple" than simply "many."  Michael Kandel notes, aptly in my opinion, "multiple has traditionally had a narrower sense: that many elements or parts belong to or are involved in one thing or one event. "  He goes on to cite Bryan Garner for the proposition   that "multiple" for "many" is "officialese."  https://style.mla.org/many-or-multiple/

Comment: I think I have enough to confidently answer my question, but I'd welcome someone who wants to test my conclusion that "multiple" is correct for "more than one," but it's lazy to use it that way.  Thanks to the moderators, who prompted me to look a little harder by closing my question.

Comment: https://www.englishforums.com/English/MultipleVsMany/brgrbk/post.htm - Many people who agree that "multiple" is bloated language to say "many."  Though numerous people posting the same opinion *is* be an appropriate use of "multiple"...

Comment: You really need to give sentences -and- intended meanings in which you're hearing 'multiple'. Almost all words have different meanings depending on context. In one context it may be perfect and in another abhorrent. Just saying "Someone said 'multiple' is wrong" underspecified.

Comment: @Mitch As you wish. Thanks for a helpful suggestion.

Comment: One difference might be that "many" means several, a lot; while "multiple" means more than one, or more than 2, which is less than many. To me it seems reasonable to contrast single with multiple. Obviously if you're objecting on aesthetic reasons (because multiple is longer, or Latinate or polysyllabic, or has that ugly "muh" sound and a syllabic /l/), then nuances of meaning may be less important than other aesthetic factors.

Comment: @Roister excellent... thanks for the edits. That part is clear now. As to the main question, where do you think this connotation of divisinon or replication might come in? (I don't doubt it, I'm just not thinking of an example at the moment).